# What's the meaning for "will have done" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The title under which this course of lectures has been announced
>   is somewhat amphibious: ‘Philosophical Elements of a Theory of
>   Society’. Some of you **will have racked** your brains and asked, ‘So
>   is that philosophy or sociology?’ And only those who have been
>   exposed to my corrupting influence for some time **will have recalled**
>   that I do not make the distinction between these disciplines as
>   separate trades so strictly, in keeping with what Mr Horkheimer said
>   yesterday in his introductory seminar course: philosophy is anything
>   but a trade.

Google says

> The FUTURE PERFECT TENSE indicates that an action will have been completed (finished or "perfected") at some point in the future. This tense is formed with "will" plus "have" plus the past participle of the verb (which can be either regular or irregular in form): "I will have spent all my money by this time next year. I will have run successfully in three marathons if I can finish this one."

What does this form mean here semantically?

Answer (score 2):

One of the meanings given by Oxford Dictionaries for  *will* is:

expressing probability or expectation about something in the present. -
"they will be miles away by now"

The author expects that his readers *will* be puzzled by his title; he imagines that some 'have racked their brains' while others 'have recalled' something they know about him.